# python arrange images on canvas in a circle

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have bunch of images (say 10) I have generated both as array or PIL object.

I need to integrate them into a circular fashion to display them and it should adjust itself to the resolution of the screen, is there anything in python that can do this?

I have tried using paste, but figuring out the resolution canvas and positions to paste is painful, wondering if there is an easier solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can say that points are arranged evenly in a circle when there is a constant angle `theta` between neighboring points. `theta` can be calculated as 2*pi radians divided by the number of points. The first point is at angle `0` with respect to the x axis, the second point at angle `theta*1`, the third point at angle `theta*2`, etc.

Using simple trigonometry, you can find the X and Y coordinates of any point that lies on the edge of a circle. For a point at angle `ohm` lying on a circle with radius `r`:

```
xFromCenter = r*cos(ohm)
yFromCenter = r*sin(ohm)
```

Using this math, it is possible to arrange your images evenly on a circle:

```
import math
from PIL import Image

def arrangeImagesInCircle(masterImage, imagesToArrange):
    imgWidth, imgHeight = masterImage.size

    #we want the circle to be as large as possible.
    #but the circle shouldn't extend all the way to the edge of the image.
    #If we do that, then when we paste images onto the circle, those images will partially fall over the edge.
    #so we reduce the diameter of the circle by the width/height of the widest/tallest image.
    diameter = min(
        imgWidth  - max(img.size[0] for img in imagesToArrange),
        imgHeight - max(img.size[1] for img in imagesToArrange)
    )
    radius = diameter / 2

    circleCenterX = imgWidth  / 2
    circleCenterY = imgHeight / 2
    theta = 2*math.pi / len(imagesToArrange)
    for i, curImg in enumerate(imagesToArrange):
        angle = i * theta
        dx = int(radius * math.cos(angle))
        dy = int(radius * math.sin(angle))

        #dx and dy give the coordinates of where the center of our images would go.
        #so we must subtract half the height/width of the image to find where their top-left corners should be.
        pos = (
            circleCenterX + dx - curImg.size[0]/2,
            circleCenterY + dy - curImg.size[1]/2
        )
        masterImage.paste(curImg, pos)

img = Image.new("RGB", (500,500), (255,255,255))

#red.png, blue.png, green.png are simple 50x50 pngs of solid color
imageFilenames = ["red.png", "blue.png", "green.png"] * 5
images = [Image.open(filename) for filename in imageFilenames]

arrangeImagesInCircle(img, images)

img.save("output.png")
```

Result:

[image]