# Trying to plot coordinates around the edge of a circle

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, points

I am trying to plot coordinates around a circle programmatically.  Here it is hard-coded to show what I am after:

http://jsfiddle.net/jE26S/1/

```
var iteration = 4;
var left = [94,200,104,-6];
var top = [-6,94,200,94];    

for(var i=0; i<iteration; i++){

    $("#center").append("<div class='point' style='left:"+left[i]+"px;top:"+top[i]+"px'></div>");    

}
```

Math is definitely not my strong point.

I need to represent people as small Circles standing around a large circle. However,  there will be random numbers of people and they all need to be equidistant.  I'm not sure whether I should be working from a central point.

Comment: Working from a central point is a good idea. For a circle whose center is `(a,b)` and has radius `r`, the position of a point on the circle's edge is `(a+r*cos(angle), b+r*sin(angle))`. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383112/python-arrange-images-on-canvas-in-a-circle/13384396#13384396) is a SO problem which is very similar to yours.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Assuming that `(x0, y0)` is the center of your circle, and `r` is the radius:

```
var items = 4;
for(var i = 0; i < items; i++) {

    var x = x0 + r * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * i / items);
    var y = y0 + r * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / items);   
    $("#center").append("<div class='point' style='left:"+ x +"px;top:"+ y +"px'></div>");    

}
```

Comment: Yup, you'll probably want to subtract the width/height of your point depending on which quadrant the result ends up in

Comment: Hi John could you please tell me how i can adjust the above code so that all the small circles are flush (justing touching) each other i.e removing the gap between little circles? thanks

Comment: Set their diameter to the value of the circumference of the large circle divided by the number of small circles.